# How to get Arabic content from MSSQL server using ODBC connection?

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, odbc

How can i get arabic data from MSSQL database using ODBC connection?
It appears as *????*.
I tried below listed solutions which are not working for me.

```
1) 'Name'=>iconv("unicode", "utf-8", $row["Name"]),
2) 'Name'=>iconv("Arabic_CI_AS", "utf-8", $row["Name"]),
3) mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
4) mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
5) <meta charset="UTF-8" />
6) 'Name'=>mb_convert_encoding($row["Name"], 'UTF-8', 'SJIS'),
```

Code snippet:

```
$customer_query="select serial,CR_ID,Name,Email,Customer_NameE from [CRM].[005_Customers_tbl]";
    $query = odbc_exec($link,$customer_query);
    $total_count=odbc_num_rows($query);
    $json = array();
    if($total_count>0){
        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
            $json[] = array('serial'=>$row['serial'],
                    'CR_ID'=>$row['CR_ID'],
                    'Name'=>$row["Name"],
                    'Email'=>$row['Email'],
                    'Customer_NameE'=>$row['Customer_NameE']);
        }
    }
    $result['customer']=$json;
```

I know that it's achievable using change collation of table but it's not possible for this application due to some limitations.

Any other possibilities to achieve that ?

Comment: mysql_query can't work on MSSQL Server. It's a different database system.

Comment: Whenever it comes to *non-plain-ASCII* characters you should use `NVARCHAR` in SQL Server instead of `VARCHAR` with a `COLLATION`. In this case you'd shift unicode (`UCS-2` actually) from system to system. SQL Server does not support `UTF-8`, where some characters take 2 (or even more bytes). The *single-byte-strings* are *extended ASCII*, where the upper code table (128 to 255) is depeding on the collation / code page...

Comment: Showing error like "'UCS-2' not supported"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to put below line

```
 <meta charset="UCS-2"/>
```

and do casting in query like this

```
$var = "select CAST(Name as VARBINARY(150) as Name) form $table_name;
```

and then use this line for convert ??? text to arabic language.

```
$name = iconv('UCS-2LE','UTF-8',$name)
```